# Should Calculations be done in SurfaceView or seperate Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, surfaceview

So over the last few months I've created a fairly complex game that's near ready for release. The only problem left is that it is running as smoothly as I would hope and I think this is  because of the way I have structured my threads. Right everything in my code is done through a surfaceview. All calculations, position updates, drawing, collisions, etc are done there. I was wondering if I am supposed to put all updates into one thread then handle only drawing in the surfacethread. Is this the proper way to do it, if so how would i implement that(asynctask,thread,handler,etc)?

Comment: While old you may want to look at the source for http://replicalisland.net and the video http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html. Do be aware that Asynctask has changed from serial to parallel to serial in the various versions of Android.

Comment: so do I put the calculations in a seperate thread or not?

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. If your game is running just fine(even on slower hardware), then there's not really a *need* for it. I do it as a matter of practice, but only because my first few projects ended up **not** running fine by the time they were done, so at that point it became necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you should avoid doing any time-consuming calculation in the UI Thread. You could also incur in an ANR error message.

You can either use:

- `AsyncTask`, but be aware that it has some flaws and drawbacks. For example it isn't guaranteed to even start or complete.
- `IntentServices` or `HandlerThreads` if you need to do operations that need to be executed sequentially in a worker thread
- `WorkerThreadPool` if you need to execute true parallel tasks.